# Why are states called locations in Timed Automata?

Tags: terminology, automata

I started reading about [timed automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timed_automaton) lately. In the definition, they have *locations* instead of *states* as in [automata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory). Can anyone explain why is this?

Comment: Do you mean [Alur & Dill](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~alur/TCS94.pdf)'s timed automata? They call them *states*. If you are referring to some form of timed Petri net: Petri nets are said to contain *places* rather than states. This is because the system's state is distributed across the places.

Comment: @reinierpost Thank you for giving the original paper. Basically, I was reading it from some study materials from the web, e.g., http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xpelanek/IA158/TA-intro.pdf, http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/Publis/PAPERS/PDF/BL-litron08.pdf

Comment: It would help to edit your question to link to the specific references you are reading that use "locations" instead of "states": we want you to include all relevant information in the question, not just leave it in the comments.  Also, if you now know enough (based on reinierpost's comment) to answer your own question, you might want to post an answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is mainly a matter of avoiding ambiguity.

At any moment in a Timed Automaton (TA), available transitions depend on the current location and the current clock valuation.
Thus, the current *state* is the combination of the current control state (or *location*) and the current *clock valuation*.

If you see a Finite State Automaton as a TA with $0$ clocks, only one clock valuation is possible, and it is the same for every states.
The clock valuation is thus irrelevant, and the current state is entirely determined by the current location.
To simplify the vocabulary, we identify both terms.

The word "location" is often used because it is hard to mistake it for "state".
But it is not uncommon to see "discrete state" instead of "location", and "extended state" instead of "state".

Comment: Note that this distinction also occurs in other extended automata models, like pushdown automata (state = location + stack contents).